# iframe doesn't work with stick footer

Tags: html, css, iframe, sticky-footer

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aKkFR/

I followed the steps to sticky footer here: http://blog.softlayer.com/2012/tips-and-tricks-pure-css-sticky-footers/

So far, so good. However, when I add an `iframe` in my `#content` div, the footer disappears. Any idea as to why this happens and can this be fixed?

Comment: in your jfiddle code i did'nt find your iframe code.

Comment: @ManishSingh http://jsfiddle.net/aKkFR/2/ here is the code with the iframe; but as expected, the footer disappears.

Comment: <iframe width=100% id="cframe" frameborder=0 src="http://www.google.com">
                </iframe> try this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 doesn't support self-closing tags, you need to use `</iframe>`. [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aKkFR/3/)

What's happening: anything past that `<iframe>` tag is being considered as "fallback content" for browsers that don't support iframes. The same way you do it with video:

```
<video src=video.mp4> Your browser doesn't support videos. </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <iframe width=100% id="cframe" frameborder=0 src="google.com"> 
   </iframe>
```